# Remove Cell Content & Shift Up Without Sort

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

@Doug Clancy on this site offered some very much appreciated guidance and solution (shown below), which clears cell content and where necessary shifts the rows up to fill those that are blank.

```
Sub DelRow()
Dim RangeToClear As Range
Dim msg As VbMsgBoxResult

Sheets("Input").Protect "handsoff", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
Application.EnableEvents = False
msg = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", vbYesNo)
If msg = vbNo Then Exit Sub
With Selection
    Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:S"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("T:AE"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RangeToClear = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0    ' or previously defined error handler
    If Not RangeToClear Is Nothing Then
        RangeToClear.ClearContents
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Range("A7:AG400").Sort Key1:=Range("B7"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("C:AE"), .EntireRow).Locked = True
    Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("AG:AG"), .EntireRow).Locked = True
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The code correctly works, but I have a slight problem, through no fault of @Doug Clancy, more a change in my requirements.

To guide users on which row they need to add new records to, I've set a text signal i.e. "Enter your name", which always appears on the first empty row, ready for the user to add a new record. Unfortunately, this value is also picked up on the sort, which is where my problem lies.

I've been trying for a few days now to come up with a solution whereby the 'Sort' function is removed from the above code, with the remaining functionality left intact. Unfortunately without any success.

Could someone please, please have a look at this and offer some guidance on how I can remove the sorting of the cells.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: How about instead of using the text "Enter your name here", use cell formatting... Like Red Highlighted cell. You can take the highlighting off once the cell contains some text. You also may be able to automate Conditional Formatting to get the text you want to display without there actually being text in the cell.

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltzman, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I had thought about this way of doing things. For the moment though, I'd like to see if I can get this working. Kind regards. Chris

Comment: In that case end your sort range 1 cell before the cell with "Enter your name here"

Comment: @IRHM When you say " which always appears on the first empty row, ready for the user to add a new record", do you mean that there are various rows that are reserved for designating a section of the worksheet reserved for various employees (i.e., each employee has their own specific section in the workbook)? Or do you mean the first empty row in the sheet has an employee name in each column or something like that?

Comment: Hi @Lopsided, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post, and my apologies for not replying sooner. I've been working on this over the last few days and have put together a working solution, which you'll see in the post below. Once again many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Answer (score 1):

After working on this over the last few days, I've put together the following solution:

```
Sub DelRow()

Dim DoesItExist As Range
Dim msg As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim RangeToClear As Range

Sheets("Input").Protect "handsoff", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
Application.EnableEvents = False
msg = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", vbYesNo)
If msg = vbNo Then Exit Sub
With Range("B7", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .Value = Evaluate("if(" & .Address & "<>"""",if(isnumber(search(""Enter your name""," & _
        .Address & ")),""""," & .Address & "),"""")")
End With
With Selection
    Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:S"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("T:AE"), .EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RangeToClear = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0    ' or previously defined error handler
    If Not RangeToClear Is Nothing Then
        RangeToClear.ClearContents
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("A7:AG400").Sort Key1:=Range("B7"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("C:AE"), .EntireRow).Locked = True
    Application.Intersect(.Parent.Range("AG:AG"), .EntireRow).Locked = True
End With
    Set DoesItExist = Sheets("Input").Range("B7:B10").Find("Enter your name")
       If Not DoesItExist Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       Sheets("Input").Select
       Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Enter your name"
       Columns("B:B").Locked = False  ' to unlock the whole column
       Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```