# ClearContents and Shift Data Below up without deleting rows/cells

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset

I automating a spreadsheet cleaning tools that removes data from the spreadsheet if certain values are in a particular column.  Originally, it deleted entire rows of data if the specific value is found.  However, this is causing numerous reference errors by deleting the rows.  Sample of the original code below.

```
Set rData = .Range("L5:L" & last & ",AX5:AX" & last)
    For i = rData.Row To rData.Row + rData.Rows.Count - 1
        If .Range("AX" & i) = "DONE" Or .Range("AX" & i) = "CANCEL" Then
            .Range("A" & i, "AX" & i).Copy

            bottom = activewkb.Worksheets("OrderStatus").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            activewkb.Worksheets("OrderStatus").Range("A" & bottom).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            If i > 0 Then
                .Range("D" & i & ":CA" & i).ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

The easiest way to get rid of the reference errors is to clear the contents from column D through DD if the requirements are satisfied then shift all of the data below it up for column D to DD up one row.  The new code is below.  I am getting an error on the .Range("D" & i).Offset(1,0).Value line.

```
Set rData = .Range("L5:L" & last & ",AX5:AX" & last)
    For i = rData.Row To rData.Row + rData.Rows.Count - 1
        If .Range("AX" & i) = "DONE" Or .Range("AX" & i) = "CANCEL" Then
            .Range("A" & i, "AX" & i).Copy

            bottom = activewkb.Worksheets("OrderStatus").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            activewkb.Worksheets("OrderStatus").Range("A" & bottom).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            If i > 0 Then
                .Range("D" & i & ":CA" & i).ClearContents
                .Range("D" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value
                .Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easier to get rid of the 'reference errors' (which you didn't think were important enough to include).

Comment: Because extraordinary circumstances, we are unable to get rid of the reference errors and have to find a work around.

Comment: Why not use `.Range("D" & i & ":CA" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp`?

Comment: You're getting an error because the statement`.Range("D" & i).Offset(1,0).Value` is not valid (it doesn't do anything); You may want to do this: `.Range("D" & i & ":CA" & i) = .Range("D" & i+1 & ":CA" & i+1)`, but this should be done in a separate loop going from the last row to the first

Comment: Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941293/remove-cell-content-shift-up-without-sort